# Error: MODIFY FILE failed. Size is greater than MAXSIZE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to resize a database in SQL Server 2012. I am getting the following error:

> Msg 5040, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   MODIFY FILE failed. Size is greater than MAXSIZE.

What is the reason for this error. What can we do to overcome this?

```
 use master
 go
 alter database tempdb modify file
  (name = tempdev,
  size = 2MB,
  maxsize = 3MB,
  filegrowth = 1KB)
 go
```

Comment: filegrowth = 1KB? It seem space is still very expensive...

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that your temp db is already bigger than 3MB. 3MB seems very small to me and could lead to issues with your queries and maintenance routines (which use the temp db while re-indexing and other procedures)

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart the database.
The size of 'tempdb' will shrink after the restart.
Then set the 'tempdb' MAXSIZE.